# NO ingresa a metodo de una clase internal c#

Tags: c#, poo, mysqlconnector

Estoy tratando de comprender porque no ejecuta un método desde una clase publica no estática (`public class DatosHandler`), aun método estatico:

```
public class DatosHandler
{

    public static DataTable ConsultaFacturasAll()
    {

        //*** cadena de texto de consulta de las facturas detalle*** 
        string ConsultaEncabezado = "SELECT " +
                                    "facturaNumero, " +
                                    "DATE_FORMAT(facturaFecha, '%Y-%m-%d') as FacturaFecha, " +
                                    "DATE_FORMAT(facturaFechaVencimiento, '%Y-%m-%d') as FacturaFechaVencimiento, " +
                                    "facturaOrdenCompra, " +
                                    "clienteNombre, " +
                                    "clienteIdentificacion, " +
                                    "clienteTelefono, " +
                                    "clienteEmail, " +
                                    "FORMAT(facturaSubtotal, 2)  as facturaSubtotal, " +
                                    "FORMAT(facturaValorTotal, 2) as facturaValorTotal FROM Encabezados";

        return Conexion.EjecutarConsulta(ConsultaEncabezado, CommandType.Text); // ACA SALE EL ERROR

    }
```

la Clase que se invoca el método EjecutarConsulta es internal y métodos Static como lo coloco en el recuadro:

```
public static DataTable EjecutarConsulta(string cadenaComando, CommandType tipocomando)
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter();// aca he colocado punto de interrupcion pero no llega el debuger en este punto
        adaptador.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(cadenaComando, conexion);
        adaptador.SelectCommand.CommandType = tipocomando;

        DataSet resultado = new DataSet();
        adaptador.Fill(resultado);

        return resultado.Tables[0];
    }
```

El error que me muestra es:

> Se produjo una excepción en el inicializador de tipo de 'co.InfraestructuraData.Conexion'

Tengo bien referenciados los dll a mysql, la consulta esta bien (hice prueba)

pero al hacer debug `return Conexion.EjecutarConsulta(ConsultaEncabezado, CommandType.Text);` en esta linea sale la excepción en el inicializador de tipo.

Me podrían explicar porque no ingresa al llamado de la clase Conexión ejecutar consulta??? Está definido como `static`!

```
public static DataTable EjecutarConsulta
```

Tanto la clase `Conexión` como `DatosHandler` están en el mismo proyecto o espacio de nombres  `namespace co.InfraestructuraData`

En lo posible explicar con código Gracias! ;) ;)

**Actualización**

este es el codigo de la clase internal Conexion, y se encuentran en el mismo espacio de nombres namespace co.InfraestructuraData

```
internal class Conexion
{

    private static string cadenaConexion= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlConexionApp"].ConnectionString;
    private static MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);

    public static bool Conectar()
    {
        try
        {
            conexion.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void Desconectar()
    {
        conexion.Close();
    }

    public static void EjecutarOperacion(string cadenaComando, List<MySqlParameter> listaparametros, CommandType tipoComando)
    {
        if (Conectar())
        {
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
            comando.CommandText = cadenaComando;
            comando.CommandType = tipoComando;
            comando.Connection = conexion;

            foreach (MySqlParameter parametro in listaparametros)
            {
                comando.Parameters.Add(parametro);
            }
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Desconectar();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No se pudo establecer conexion");
        }
    }

    public static DataTable EjecutarConsulta(string sentencia, List<MySqlParameter> listaparametro, CommandType tipocomando)
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adaptador.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sentencia, conexion);
        adaptador.SelectCommand.CommandType = tipocomando;
        foreach (MySqlParameter parametro in listaparametro)
        {
            adaptador.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(parametro);
        }
        DataSet resultado = new DataSet();
        adaptador.Fill(resultado);

        return resultado.Tables[0];
    }

    public static DataTable EjecutarConsulta(string cadenaComando, CommandType tipocomando)
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adaptador.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(cadenaComando, conexion);
        adaptador.SelectCommand.CommandType = tipocomando;

        DataSet resultado = new DataSet();
        adaptador.Fill(resultado);

        return resultado.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: De donde obtiene tu método estático `conexion`?

Comment: Como lo mencionas la clase que contiene el metodo **EjecutarConsulta** es internal, lo cual solo puede ser utilizada en el mismo assembly, si esta en otro proyecto y estas referenciando la dll, pues podras ejecutarlo almenos que remuevas la palabra reservada *internal*

Comment: Por cierto..tambien sería interesante conocer la `InnerException`(si la hay) de la excepción que te está saltando

Comment: Y por último...es posible que tu clase `Conexion` esté intentando acceder a alguna clave de configuración (por ejemplo, `ConnectionString`) que no exista?

Comment: @Pikoh de una clase internal, adjunte en la actualizacion la clase.

Comment: @Elcainas como lo explique en la actualización esta en el mismo NameSpace co.InfraestructuraData DatosHandler y Conexion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando se efectúa una llamada a un método estático de una clase, se debe tener en cuenta que todas las variables estáticas de la clase son inicializadas.

En tu caso, tienes dos variables estáticas en `Conexion`: `cadenaConexion` y `conexion`.

El error que describes lo está lanzando la inicialización de alguna de esas variables. O bien la clave `sqlConexionApp` no existe en tu fichero de configuración (`web.config` o `app.config`), o bien la cadena de conexión no es correcta y el error se está produciendo en `conexion = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);`

Debes comprobar ambas cosas, y también en estos casos normalmente la `InnerException` te debe dar más información sobre cual es el problema.

Comment: la Clave estaba sqlConexionAp faltandole una "p" Gracias Pikoh

Answer (score 1):

Debes procurar que la versión de tu librería sea igual a la base de datos mysql que usas, las versiones son 5.1 y 5.2, etc; Aunque ya tengas instalada tu librería debes revisar que sean la misma versión.

Te muestro parte de la clase conexión:
para usar el método solo crea una instancia de la clase

```
MySqlHelper mc = new MySqlHelper();
mc.EjecutarConsulta("SELECT * ...");
```

Puedes agregar los métodos que quieras algo como:

```
public DataTable EjecutarConsulta(string cadenaComando){
 try{
    var dbCon = Instance();
    if (!dbCon.IsConnect())
      throw new Exception("CP: No es posible establecer la conexión");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cadenaComando, dbCon._connection);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    return dt;
 }catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}
```

Te dejo el codigo:

```
    public class MySqlHelper
    {
        private MySqlHelper()
        {
        }


        private string _Host { get; set; } = "localhost";
        private string _databaseName { get; set; } = "BASE";
        private string _usid { get; set; } = "USER";
        private string _password { get; set; } = "***";

        public MySqlConnection _connection { get; set; } = null;

        private static MySqlHelper _instance = null;

        private static MySqlHelper Instance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new MySqlHelper();
            return _instance;
        }

        private bool IsConnect()
        {
            if (_connection == null)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_databaseName))
                    return false;
                string connstring = string.Format("Server={0}; database={1}; UID={2}; password={3};charset=utf8", _Host, _databaseName, _usid, _password);
                _connection = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
                _connection.Open();
            }

            return true;
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pasa un sql Command de tipo Text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmd"></param>
    /// <param name="Timeout"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ExecCommad(MySqlCommand cmd, int Timeout = 45)
    {
        var dbCon = Instance();
        try
        {
            if(cmd == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("CP: No se mando ningun parametro o no puede ser null :(");

            if (!dbCon.IsConnect())
                throw new Exception("CP: No es posible establecer la conexión");

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = Timeout;//60 = 1 minutos
            cmd.Connection = dbCon._connection;
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            var getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return (getValue == null) ? string.Empty : getValue.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        finally { dbCon.Close(); cmd.Dispose(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pasa un Sql command param de tipo proc
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cmd"></param>
    /// <param name="Timeout"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string ExecProc(MySqlCommand cmd, int Timeout = 45)
    {
        var dbCon = Instance();
        try
        {
            if(cmd==null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("CP: No se mando ningun parametro o no puede ser null :(");

            if (cmd.CommandType != CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                throw new ArgumentException("CP: Solo se pueden usar comandos tipos proc :(");

            if (!dbCon.IsConnect())
                throw new Exception("CP: No es posible establecer la conexión");


            cmd.Connection = dbCon._connection;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = Timeout;//60 = 1 minutos
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            var getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return (getValue == null) ? string.Empty : getValue.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        finally { dbCon.Close(); cmd.Dispose(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias @Jjcc ya se resolvio la pregunta, pero el aporte esta bien